# How to get adjusted close prices from Morningstar in Python?

Tags: python, stock

I'm trying to get adjusted close prices for stock data using Morningstar API but I'm only able to get the close prices not the adjusted close. Can someone help me figure out why?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import statsmodels.api as sm
from pandas.core import datetools



start = datetime(2015, 2, 9)
end = datetime(2017, 5, 24)
short_window = 40
long_window = 100
def get(stocks, startdate, enddate):
    def data(ticker):
        return                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ( web.DataReader(ticker,'morningstar', start, end))
        datas = map (data, stocks)
    return(web.DataReader(datas, stocks, ['Ticker', 'Date']))

stocks = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM', 'GOOG']
all_data = web.DataReader(stocks, 'morningstar', start, end)

print(all_data)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJbLW.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you show us some code?

Comment: I just did, thank you!